# Paste URL with text selected should create a link

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, editor

When I'm writing an answer, this is what I do when I want to insert a link.

1. Select the text for the link
2. Click the `link` icon (or type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
3. Paste the URL

It would be easier and faster if you could simply paste a URL while text is selected in the edit box, and some clever JavaScript would create the link.

1. Select the text for the link
2. Paste the URL

On some other sites, it works like this, and it feels very natural to me. Hence this suggestion.

Comment: Could you elaborate? If you enter a bare URL, whether by pasting or whatever, it's rendered as a link. What do you want to change there? Be specific please.

Comment: @Deduplicator That doesn't convert the selected text to a hyperlink. So idea is select text "abc", paste something that looks like a hyperlink and "abc" becomes a link, not overwritten. `[abc][1]`

Comment: Indeed, what Martin Smith says.

Comment: I honestly never use that. I always type the markup for links myself `[title](http://google.com)`...

Comment: @MartinSmith That would be *very* surprising. So much that I rejected that interpretation subconsciously. Let's please *not* go there and break all common traditions for how an editor works.

Comment: @XavierGuihot is it really necessary to bump a question like this to the top of the active list just to change that?

Comment: @XavierGuihot fair enough. Yeah on meta active isn't quite as active :p.

Answer (score 9):

It's standard since time immemorial that pasting text while having other text selected replaces, instead of doing some kind of arbitrary and convoluted transformation.

Please don't break such expected behavior.

Comment: I don't understand the overwhelmingly negative response. Yes, it breaks a tradition. So? Sometimes, breaking traditions is a good thing. It could be an optional feature, enabled/disabled in your personal settings. Also, how many times have you selected a bit of text with a link in your paste buffer, intending to *replace* the text, compared to intending to create a link?

Comment: I haven't counted the number of times I replaced a link or part of one. And breaking the user experience needs a really good reason, which this isn't, especially as the other use is useful.

Answer (score -1):

Sad that this question received such a negative response. Maybe it was a few years too early.

I believe that it doesn't break the expected behaviour: it enhances it. At least it's how I reacted the first time I discovered this (*oh wow this is cool*).

This behaviour is implemented in GitHub, Slack, Jira, Bitbucket, a [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yzhang.markdown-all-in-one#others), it feels natural and is very useful to me:

[image: GitHub]

[image: Slack]

As to the possibility of correcting links once pasted, it's possible directly with the way GitHub does it (first screenshot), and it takes only one click with the way Slack does it (secons screenshot). So if, let's say, 90% of the links don't require edition, then it's better to improve the usability for those 90%, even if the other 10% need one more click to be corrected.

PS: « it's standard since time immemorial » is an [appeal to tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_tradition).

Comment: This feature request will become redundant anyway once the [new stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release) is deployed network-wide since it does have that feature.